# Spring Boot Store large JSON file

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

First of all, give thanks for reading my question and try to help me and apologize for my English.

I'm trying to store geojson file as jsonb. I'm using Spring Boot (JPA + Hibernate) and Postgressql.

There is no problem when I've tried to upload a file with 5 KB. But when I'm trying to upload a large file as 21 MB I'll have to wait a long time and web showme a timeout.

How can increase time to bind the parameter that I use to store json data?

Do you recomend better implementation?

```
@Entity(name = "Scheme")
@Table(name = "maps_scheme")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Accessors(chain = true)
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class Scheme extends BaseEntityActivable implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SCHEME_SEQ_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SCHEME_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "seq_scheme", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "scheme_id")
    private Long schemeId;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "tablegojson", columnDefinition = "jsonb", nullable = false)
    private String tablegeojson;

}
```

Controller:

```
@POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @PermitAll
    public SchemeVO createScheme(@Context final UriInfo uriInfo, 
            @NotNull(message = AxisMapsErrorConstants.JSON_FILE_CANT_BE_EMPTY) @FormDataParam(ApiParam.PARAM_FILE) final InputStream file,
            @FormDataParam(ApiParam.PARAM_NAME) final String name,
            @FormDataParam(ApiParam.PARAM_DESCRIPTION) final String description,
            @FormDataParam(ApiParam.PARAM_ATTACHMENT_ID) final String attachmentId,
            @FormDataParam(ApiParam.PARAM_FILE_PATH) final String filePath
            ) {
        return schemeService.createScheme(AxisMapsUtil.getLoggedUsername(), name, description, file, attachmentId, filePath, SchemeVO.class);
    }
```

I dont have any error... only that if there is a better way to increse insert data as jsonb.

This is an example of [geojson](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/demos/choropleth-studio-gl/stateData.geojson)

Comment: Can you please provide the code of your Controller that receives the data, the code that you're using to send the data and the exact error message (is there an exception thrown in the Spring Boot application?)?

Comment: I dont have any error... only that if there is a better way to increse insert data as jsonb

Comment: Are you using Tomcat (servlet stack) as the webserver or netty (webflux stack)? I assume you're on Tomcat?

Comment: If you don't get any error in Spring Boot.. does the upload work as expected (jsonb gets saved to the db) but only your browser shows a time out?

Is your application behind an Apache or Nginx reverse-proxy? The timeout you're running can also come from their timeout.